# Jenkins pipeline performance report build failure due to wrong different calculation

Tags: performance, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I am running jmeter test using jenkins pipeline and performance plugin .

but build is getting failed due to below message

```
 TG01_TS01_RTPSR_WB_HR24_NavigateThroughWebsiteGroups - JSR223_Reset Variables for next iteration                                         0                   1                   192233720368547760.00%

The label "TG01_TS01_RTPSR_WB_HR24_NavigateThroughWebsiteGroups - JSR223_Reset Variables for next iteration" caused the build to fail
```

and my jenkins pipeline parameters are

```
perfReport compareBuildPrevious: true, filterRegex: '', ignoreFailedBuilds: true, ignoreUnstableBuilds: true, modeOfThreshold: true,relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 80.0, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 80.0, sourceDataFiles: "/Results/${params.reportName}.csv"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you have a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere in your script which is doing some helper stuff and the current build is failing because this sampler response time was higher than the threshold you configured.

I don't think you should include the metrics for this JSR223 Sampler into your reports, just add the next line somewhere:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()
```

Demo:

[image]
More information:

- [SampleResult.setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: thanks Dmitri ..  even with this it failed TG02_TS01_RTPSR_DE_HR20_LoadResourcePageOncePerUser - GET_Get Alerts                                                                   192                 517                 325             169.27%

The label "TG02_TS01_RTPSR_DE_HR20_LoadResourcePageOncePerUser - GET_Get Alerts" caused the build to fail..   basically i dont want my build to fail even if there is deviation .. just want  comparison report with previous build